# HTML tags don't appear in DOM when included using ng-include

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to include a file using ng-include.

the side-bar appear in the UI but when I say view page source that time the HTML tags of the side-bar doesn't appear.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you share the code for this?

Answer (score 1):

That is because when you view the source of an HTML page in any browser, it will perform a fresh GET of the original document and display that source code. Since AngularJS injects elements to the DOM dynamically (and because it is "just" JavaScript all together), the original generated by the server-side will not be modified. To see the generated source, use a developer tool of your choice, i.e F12 Developer Tools in IE. Also, you may want to read up on the role JavaScript plays in the whole lifecycle of webpage rendering.